# How to get CN of client certificate from incoming request in Spring Boot Rest service

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

We have requirement to check the CN of certificate of client who is calling our Spring Boot Rest API. We are using undertow server.

Can you please help in here to check the CN of certificate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use @RequestAttribute(required = true) HttpServletRequest request for getting certificate CN.

Auxiliary links:
1.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/x509.html

2.
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/request-attribute.html

3.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/xref/org/springframework/security/ui/preauth/x509/X509PreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.html

Controller
[image]

Please create new util class .

and use this code for get CN fro client certificate:

[image]

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30527130)

Comment: I edited answer. Please check

Comment: Please avoid posting images (or worse, links to images) of code or errors. Anything text-based (code and errors) should be posted as text directly in the question itself and formatted properly as a [mre]. You can get more [formatting help here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You can also read about [why you shouldn't post images/links of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).